# Python -- by value vs by reference

Tags: python, methods, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Until recently, I thought Python passed parameters by value. For example,

```
def method1(n):
   n = 5
   return n

n = 1
m = method1(n)
>>> n == 5
>>> False
```

But if I pass in a list to a method, like

```
def method2(list):
   del list[0]
   return list

list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = method2(list1)
>>> list1
>>> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

it mutates the list. I did another test:

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
x = method1(l1)
>>> l1
>>> ['a','b','c','d']
```

Here the list did not change. My question is

> Why do these different cases happen?

Comment: here is a good explanation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference list is a mutable type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python always [passes by assignment](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) , even in the first case, actually the object reference is passed. But when you do an assignment inside the function, you are causing the name to refer a new object. That would not mutate the name/variable that was used to pass the value to the function (Better explained in the below example).

Example -

```
>>> def func(n):
...     n = [1,2,3,4]
...     return n
...
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> func(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

In your case, when you do `del list[0]` you are actually mutating the `list` in place (deleting the first element from it) , and hence it reflects in the place where the function was called from as well.